# Ubuntu 12.04: Adobe flash Player crashes, can't watch YouTube

Tags: flash, adobe

After doing a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 I realized the sound was missing as I played a YT video but couldn't hear a thing. I managed to troubleshoot that problem, got the sound working, then installed Cinnamon and a few applications from the Ubuntu Software Center then went back to play a video on YT but it crashed and has been ever since. I tried installing, re-installing the Adobe Flash Player, from the Ubuntu Software Centre, from their website but so far the problem persists.

Comment: Can you try this one? Despite it's not the same problem, it may help.

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/142662/how-to-solve-jitter-or-stutter-playback-via-chrome-flash-plugin-on-ubuntu-12-0][1]

Try to look what plugins are install, it could help too!

Comment: Are you using an older processor? If so take a look at /proc/cpuinfo and see if _flags_ include SSE2.

Answer (score 1):

Solution lies slightly away from package management. Adobe ships new version compiled with sse2 flag, so it is now defunct on older computers (like mine Sempron 2400+)
Problem is solved by replacing libflashplayer.so by hand.

```
mkdir /tmp/install_flash
cd /tmp/install_flash/
wget http://engels.manf.nl/archive/flash/flashplayer11_1r102_63_linux.i386.tar.gz
tar -xvzf flashplayer11_1r102_63_linux.i386.tar.gz
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/
```

enjoy.

Also, you can download plugin from official site from 'archive' section.

Answer (score 0):

I also had Flash Player problems after a clean 12.04 install on my brand new Intel Core i7 system (running 32-bit i386 Ubuntu), and tried re-installing the Flash player (several times).

One thing I found (with the help of the previous answer) was that the `libflashplayer.so` hadn't been installed at all.

It appears that the `flashplugin-installer` package (which is what I used) didn't actually install the flash player.

The `adobe-flashplugin` package does install `libflashplayer.so`, however that didn't seem to fix the problem.

I then tried the fix described above... that also didn't help.

The `adobe-flash-properties-kde`/`gtk` package s also didn't shed any light.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try FOSS alternatives: [gnash](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/) or [Lightspark](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/lightspark/)

To install lightspark:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sparkers/daily 
    sudo apt-get update 
    sudo apt-get install lightspark browser-plugin-lightspark
```