# How to solve jitter (or stutter) playback via Chrome flash plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

Since the update to 12.04, there's been a problem specifically related to audio/video playback in Google Chrome.

The problem only affected the Google version but not the Chromium nor the Firefox Browsers.

Comment: Just to add for windows users with same problem who may have stumbled across this thread like me:
I had also 3 plugin files like you see in the answer. two in \Users\...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\... and another in \Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\...

Disable the Chrome plugins but leave the Macromedia plugin active, and it'll solve the sound issues.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Update July 19th 2012:

> > > As of today, this happened once again, and I solved it with the same method, so this could apply to any version. It's not clear (at least for me) if this is a bug related to Chrome updates or something else. If someone could clarify this, I would be grateful. On the other hand, if you go down to this road, take it as a *temporary* solution.

## The solution:

Here's what I did.

1. On Google Chrome entered `chrome://plugins/` and look where the flash plugin was. I saw that there were 3 different plugins installed.

[image]

2. On the right side of the window I pressed the "+" sign on "Details".

[image]

3. I disabled (by clicking on "disable") each one of them, one at a time, and finally, after some tests, the one that worked for me was the one that was called `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so` (the "original" flash plugin, and not the integrated chrome version). 
   [image]

I'm no expert, but I think there are some problems related to the integrated version, so untill a new version is released, I'll stick to the "original" plugin.

**Hope it works for you!**

Comment: For whatever reason I only had _one_ flash plugin installed - adobes's. And still kept having these annoying audio interruptions / stuttering. Step 1 from [this official ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) did the trick. Was some sort of conflict with alsa.

Comment: Thanks _gorlum0_ for this link! this solution (only step 1) not only fixed the sound issues related to flash in Chrome, but **in Firefox** as well!! Was a little bit dubious command (as it works the kernel in some way), but worked perfectly in the end. Great!

Comment: I was able to fix this problem by doing `killall pulseaudio` and `rm -r ~/.pulse*` rather than the entire reinstallation command linked to by gorlum0. (I tried messing with about:plugins first, but it didn't completely work.)

Comment: I'm in 11.10 using Chromium 24.x. With chromium, we only have `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so`. So, no point looking at `about:plugins`. I just tried `killall pulseaudio`, and the sound stuttering in videos just stopped. Noticed that pulseaudio instance was spawned when I killed it.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 10.4 and after deleting the .pulse folder and killall, I believe it was finally deactivating BOTH flash plugins that youtube sound worked normally again. not sure how youtube is working at the moment, but it is.

Comment: This worked for me in 2015. SMH :-P