# Audio Stutter in in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound

After upgrading to precise my audio is stuttering.  It is happening, in VLC, mplayer, and anything streaming from the internet.  I followed the procedures in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure but nothing has helped so far.  There is the problem that the driver version is out of date but it does not seem to want to update with the given commands.

```
$ bash alsa-info.sh --stdout |grep version
Driver version:     1.0.24
Library version:    1.0.25
Utilities version:  1.0.25
```

How can I upgrade the driver and fix the stuttering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is specific to Google Chrome.  Unfortunately whenever Chrome is running it also interferes with audio in other places as well, but since chrome is almost always running it was difficult to track down.  Solution: switched back to firefox, as audio problems are too large to ignore.  Audio problems are gone now.  I'll check with chrome again after a few updates.

Comment: I wonder why this one got the green check-flag, because it is not a solution et al. Not even a workaround. Scroll down to Mark Tomlin's response. that's worth a try without giving up convenience.

Answer (score 4):

Once it stutters I always got rid of this problem by killing/restarting `pulseaudio`.

1. `sudo killall pulseaudio`
2. `sudo pulseaudio --system=1 --daemonize`
3. Close and re-open `chromium`

Comment: This worked like a charm for Firefox also.

Comment: Still works Ubuntu 22.04.2; apparently still relevant 10 years later

Answer (score 1):

I followed the answer/tutorial in [How to solve jitter (or stutter) playback via Chrome flash plugin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142662/how-to-solve-jitter-or-stutter-playback-via-chrome-flash-plugin) and now playback seems to work again:

1. Go to `chrome://plugins` in Chrome.
2. Activate the details by clicking on the "+"-sign which you find on the top, right side.
3. Deactivate the Chrome flash plugin: On my system it is located in `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so`.
4. Use the one which is installed together with Mozilla Firefox: On my system it is located in `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so`

Unfortunately I would not entitle this as a solution for your problem. It is more a workaround until the problems with the original Chrome flash plugin are solved. But until then you are still able to use your Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

[12.04 - Ubuntu/Linux Audio Skipping/Stuttering](http://chad.ill.ac/post/22589427042/12-04-ubuntu-linux-audio-skipping-stuttering)

I fixed this problem system wide, by changing the audio standard in my BIOS from HD to AC97. Ever since then, I've had zero problems with audio in my computer.

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: @OmarL Well, yeah, this answer is from 7 years ago. So that makes sense. It's also from an operating system that is 8 years old.

Answer (score 0):

For VLC - in the menu go to preferences.  Choose Audio settings, and change the audio output module to Alsa audio ouput.  Close and restart VLC.