# My Pulseaudio is skipping, how to fix?

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio

When I try to use audio (YouTube, Audacity, LMMS, etc.) I get this kind of skipping noise every couple of minutes (on average, sometimes it starts happening every few seconds) and so it makes watching videos and making music (or even listening to it!) almost impossible (for example "Hello" becomes "Hel-el-el-el-el-el-el-elo").

When I restart pulseaudio, it seems to stop for a couple of minutes, and then starts again. My audio was fine a couple of weeks ago, and so I have no idea what the problem could be

---

Running Lubuntu 15.04 (vivid), on a Lenovo T61 laptop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by your system running out of RAM.

- Increase your swap
- Disable the GUI on your next reboot for testing purposes
- Test using a non-memory consuming player like *mplayer* and see if the stuttering problem persists.

If this stops the stuttering problem you only have to upgrade your RAM

Comment: How much more ram would you recommend? (I already have 4GB)

Comment: Lubuntu's system requirement recommend more than 1GB , so 4GB is more than enough ,.
RAM doesn't seem to be the problem , I suggest you try the answers to  this question it may help you : http://askubuntu.com/questions/160618/audio-stutter-in-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Okay, that looks like it worked, I'll comment back if it stops working. Thanks! (For now.... :D)