# Audio stuttering?

Tags: sound

So I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04, and I have a bit of a problem. Occasionally, about every 2 minutes, there is a stutter in the audio that lasts a few seconds.
I'm a complete *Linux/Ubuntu* noob, so explain what I need to do like I'm 5. Thanks!

Comment: Let's start out with what computer you have ;)

Comment: HP Stream 13, 2015

Comment: Search for and open the Additional Drivers app. See if anything shows up.

Comment: nope, only a cpu driver which I'm already using.

Comment: Hmm. Open a terminal (ctrl + alt + t) and run `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Then, open a file browser and press ctrl+H to enable hidden files. In `Home`, look for `.config`. Open that and and delete the `pulse` folder. Reboot and see what happens.

Comment: I did that, I'm going to go watch a video now.

Comment: Sorry, there's still some stuttering

Comment: Try the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/160618/audio-stutter-in-in-ubuntu-12-04