# Installed Ubuntu about 2 months ago, never had sound issues til just a few days ago, sound will stutter and audio sounds degraded when playing music

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, alsa

Ok first things first, so I decided to switch to Unbuntu from windows, I wiped the drive and installed Ubuntu 20.4LTS. For the first week or so everything was good but then all of a sudden I noticed that when playing video there was screen tearing and screen tearing when scrolling through web pages. So I did some research and realized that I was using Ubuntu's built in third party video graphics driver called nouveau, so I went into "software and updates" and under "additional drivers" I installed Nvidia's proprietary software which fixed the issue.

So now starting about a couple of days ago I'm now having audio issues. When I'm on the internet and I'm watching youtube the audio sounds totally fine except it will stutter about once every 40 seconds or so, it's totally random. When I play music offline the music will sound horrible though! When I play music offline the audio sounds degraded and distorted, but keep in mind when I stream a song on youtube the audio sounds fine it'll just stutter here and there. I have been doing research on the internet trying to fix this issue on my own but and this point I really need help? I believe one of the things I tried was purging alsa and reinstalling it, I think thats what I did, but that didn't fix it.

By the way, I did boot up from an Ubuntu live disk and guess what, the audio was 100% fine, so this proves a glitch has occured.

So I'm a lifetime windows user and windows will inevitably glitch and the best way to fix it is to do a system restore, one time the touchpad on my windows laptop quit working so all I had to do was do a system restore to an earlier stable point and boom problem solved. Problem is linux has no built in system restore (why would linux not have a built in system restore because I believe it would easily solve this weird sound issue I'm having?), I have indeed learned of third party software called timeshift and I was going to install it but I thought that I would just wait a little while before I did, I am now seriously regretting it because it seems linux does experience the same bugs and glitches just like windows does which is why I can't believe linux doesn't have a built in system restore function.

So how can I fix this audio issue without having to wipe the drive and reinstall the operating system? Also, do any of you have experience with timeshift, would a simple system restore fix this issue like I suspect it would? I have a question about timeshift, does it work just like windows system restore, for instance, say I encountered a glitch on 2019/05/26 and I choose to restore to a point on 2019/05/06, 20 days before I encountered the glitch, but say on 2019/05/23 I downloaded a bunch of music and pics, now windows would restore back to the chosen restore point and the music and pics I had downloaded on 2019/05/23 would still be there. Does timeshift work just like this?

Comment: Wiping the hard drive and reinstalling simply because the sound isn't working perfectly should never be a consideration. I imagine a simple `pluseaudio` solution can be found. An example from a decade ago: [Audio Stutte
r in in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160618/audio-stutter-in-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Can you provide technical details? For example: the make/model of your audio adapter, the type of speaker/headphones you are using, how these components are connected, etc. Please edit your question

Comment: @Nmath What is an audio adapter and how do I find out what mine is? My computer hooks up to my 24 inch LG montior by HDMI, and then I got two simple logitech speakers that hooks up to the audio out port on the monitor, but I just now hooked my computer up to the LG monitor, previously my computer was in the living room hooked up to the 55 inch TCL TV, Doesn't matter what the computer is hooked up to the audio issue is there. I did mention earlier though that when I was running Ubuntu live CD the audio issue wasn't there which means a glitch has occurred. Wouldn't system restore fix this?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix There's an answer in there that says to go into Bios and go into advanced settings and change the audio from HD to AC97, well in my Bios there was only a setting that said HD audio and it was enabled so I disabled, this did not fix the issue. Please hep me? Why on Earth doesn't Ubuntu have a system restore functionality built in? I am telling you if this were windows and all of a sudden I started having an audio issue the first thing I'd do is do a system restore which always fixed the problem. Do you recommend timeshift? Can you tell me what to do?

Comment: @Nmath You know if I were still on windows and this happened all I would do is do a system restore to an earlier stable point, system restore always fixed my problems on windows, why would Ubuntu not include a system restore functionality built in? Wouldn't system restore fix this issue? Because here I am crying and feeling hopeless that I can't fix my computer, I'm totally stumped here! How can I fix this without having to wipe the drive and reinstall the operating system, of course this time I'll be using timeshift, cause these bugs happen inevitably right? Has Ubuntu been bug free for you?

Comment: The audio adapter is usually built into the motherboard and would be identified in your motherboard's documentation. But it sounds like you might not be using your motherboard audio and are connecting audio by way of HDMI. Is this a desktop computer? Are you using a dedicated GPU? If so, which model and are you using a proprietary driver (if available- for example, Nvidia). There is no system restore, but you have the ultimate power to undo changes that were made to your device. Did the problems onset correlate with related software changes, like updates to drivers or audio related software?

Comment: This appears to be a problem created by the user. With no details of the hardware, drivers, nor how all hardware is connected, impossible to assist. But, given the user changed from nouveau to nvidia driver, and the a/v is proper when running the system from a live usb stick, and the a/v is ported via the Nvidia HDMI port, I suspect the problem lies with the Nvidia card and driver mismatch.  I suggest the user install Synaptic and use it to change the a/v driver back to Nouveau, connect the audio to the mobo audio port, and reboot.

Comment: If the problem disappears, the user needs to contact Nvidia for advice on which driver to use for his specific card. But given the user appears to be quite new to Ubuntu, likely he is better off to perform a fresh install and use the install defaults for his a/v. A new install should be about 20 minutes. This is likely to be quicker and easier for him than attempting to debug his mistake.

Comment: @Danny I don't use Timeshift. When you boot your computer select "Advanced Options" and then pick a previous kernel version to boot with. It is possible the newest kernel is causing sound problems.

Comment: @robgrune The GPU is an Nvidia 750 Ti, I did the terminal command to see what recommended Nvidia driver was needed, I used the GUI "additional drivers" and installed the recommended Nvidia driver 470(tested). But I switched to the recommended Nvidia driver using the GUI a few weeks ago and the sound was working fine up until a few days ago. Now guess what, as of just a couple of hours ago my sound is working fine again, I dont know why but it seems the weird glitch dissappeared on it's own lol. Have you used timeshift at all?

Comment: @Nmath Yes desktop PC that I had built for me at a computer store. It's using an Nvidia GPU 750 Ti. I checked in terminal what recommended Nvidia driver to use, it's what the GUI "additional drivers" already recommended by putting it at the top and says, Nvidia driver 470 (proprietary, tested), It's the only one in the GUI that says tested which means recommended. I had to switch from Nouveau originally because of screen tearing when playing video. Nvidia's drivers fixed the screen tearing. The sound issue appeared randomly, but as of two hours ago disappeared on it's own go figure.

Comment: @Nmath I was looking at the original receipt for the build and I am pretty sure it's an Asus motherboard, if you want I can find out exactly which model? Is there a terminal prompt for finding out that information? I have my PC hooked up to an LG monitor via HDMI, and then I have two logitech speakers hooked up to the monitor via audio out port. But hey just in the last 2 hours the sound issue went away so I'll just see if it returns. But seriously does timeshift  work just like windows system restore, will it restore without deleting files I recently downloaded like pics and music?

Comment: If your sound is coming from HDMI from your dedicated Nvidia GPU then the motherboard onboard sound is not being used. I agree with previous comments that your problem could stem from the fact that you originally used nouveau drivers and then switched to proprietary drivers after installation. I can't advise on timeshift or system restore as I am not familiar with either

Comment: Timeshift is supposed to enable restores of the system. It does not backup/restore user files. When I tried it 2 yrs ago, it did restore the files, but the grub became corrupted. I have not tried it since. In my experience, a fresh install is less time than debugging system problems, and is guaranteed to succeed. Proviso: I partition the boot disk for efi, boot, root, home partitions.

Comment: aha! the 750ti. it's old (2014) and buggy. I had problems with this card. Drivers after 390 can give problems. The 470 and 390 may share some files, so could lead to even more problems. And, Nvidia drivers can corrupt the grub. Suggest you install afresh, install Synaptic, and choose the 390 driver.