# Youtube yellow snow screen on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Google Chrome displaying artifacts in YouTube?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243313/why-is-google-chrome-displaying-artifacts-in-youtube)

When I try to watch any video from Youtube on the Google Chrome, my screen is totally normal but video is yellow snowy. What can I do about it ?

Thank you.

Aslan

Comment: A possibly relevant bug is being tracked here: [Flickering rectangles like a swarm of bees when watching youtube and vimeo videos](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164555).

Answer (score 4):

The reason for that is built in Flash player.

If you have flash player plugin installed for Firefox than you can use it in Chrome too by changing setup in `chrome://plugins`.

Select *Detailed View* and uncheck the flash plugin that is named "pepper flash" or "out-of-process."

Answer (score 0):

that helped
chrome://plugins
+details
Location:   /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
Type:   PPAPI (out-of-process)
     Disable

Comment: Please think of this site as a Wikipedia for Ubuntu users, so make a less compressed answer. Full sentences would be very welcome.

Comment: Hello All;

I did unchecked the out of process but there is no solition, by the way there was only a out of process plug-in.

Thank you.

Aslan